# Deserializing incorrect class despite casting

Tags: c#, deserialization

Having a problem while deserializing a number of objects stored as BLOBs in a MySQL database.

Each object class has its own deserialize function.

```
Class1 c1Holder = (Class1)binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
```

Works fine, but then ...

```
Class2 c2Holder = (Class2)binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
```

...calls the Class1 deserialize function. When I step through it using the VS 2010 debugger it will call the correct function on the 2nd attempt.
Also...

```
Class3 c3Holder = (Class3)binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
```

...calls the Class1 deserialize function, then the Class2 function and finally the correct function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does Class2 inherit from Class1, and Class3 from Class2?

Comment: Where does binFormatter come from ?

Comment: Is that `BinaryFormatter`? With `BinaryFormatter`, the data itself defines what gets constructed (the assembly-qualified type name is in the serialized data); so : what is in `memStream`? where did the data come from? was it a `Class1` when it was serialized?

Comment: how does the data has been serialized?

Comment: The classes do not inherit from one another.

Comment: The classes do not inherit from one another.
There is in fact also a Class 4.
I can serialize and deserialize each class separately, with no issues.
When I try to deserialize all four in a single function the deserialize function of each class is called in turn.
Class 1 works fine.
Class 2 fails during call to Class1.Deserialize then works.
Class 3 fails during call to Class1.Deserialize then Class2.Deserialize then works.
Class 4 fails during call to Class1.Deserialize then Class2.Deserialize then Class3.Deserialize then works.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Assembly.Class1' to type 'Assembly.Class4'.

Unable to cast object of type 'Assembly.Class2' to type 'Assembly.Class4'.

Unable to cast object of type 'Assembly.Class3' to type 'Assembly.Class4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Assembly.Class1' to type 'Assembly.Class4'.
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'Assembly.Class2' to type 'Assembly.Class4'.
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'Assembly.Class3' to type 'Assembly.Class4'.

This suggests that you are simply expecting the data to be a different type than it actually is. The point of BinaryFormatter is that if you serialize a Class7, then it will deserialize as a class7. With other serializers, you often need to tell it what to deserialize it as, allowing different types to be interchangeable as long as they look similar.

So with BinaryFormatter: if you want to get a Class2, *serialize* a Class2.

To be clear, the following:

```
Class2 c2Holder = (Class2)binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
```

does **not** say "deserialize this as a Class2" - it is more like:

```
object tmp = binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
Class2 c2Holder = (Class2)tmp;
```

i.e. "serialize it into whatever it is, then cast that as a Class2". If it *isnt* a Class2 it will fail. This isn't a conversion etc - is is a type-check only.

If you want advice on serialization that works with similar-but-different typed, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I modified the code as you advised and it revealed the problem. I wasn't specifically casting the object when I serialized it. When I serialize all of the objects in a single function, the serialization function calls the GetObjectData() for each class, but retains the type of the first object serialized. Once I changed my serialization code from
    `binFormatter.Serialize(memStream, c2Holder);`
to 
    `binFormatter.Serialize(memStream, (Class2) c2Holder);`
the objects deserialized perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1485779 er, that is very odd. That shouldn't affect BinaryFormatter ***at all***, unless you have custom conversion operators defined. I really think to give a full answer we'd need to see the serialize code and the classes involved. There's something still a bit "suspect" here...